# How to separate admin and user in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have two pages for admin and user. When admin logged in it will redirect to `http://localhost/ci3/admin/Adminhomepage` and when user logged in it will redirect to `http://localhost/ci3/user/Userhomepage`. After logged in as user if I changed url like this`http://localhost/ci3/admin/Adminhomepage` it will directly go to admin home page. I want like it will go to admin login page `http://localhost/ci3/admin/Adminlogin`. I have userId and permissions for admin like view,edit,add and deleteRole. In this anyone is set to `1` then he is admin otherwise he is user. I want to write that logic in Admin_controller.

### Admin_controller

```
<?php
class Admin_controller extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("Adminmodel","",true);   
        
        $userId =  $this->session->userdata('cp_adminid');
        
        $toCheck = $this->Adminmodel->tocheckadmin($userId);            
    }
}
?>
```

### Admin_model

```
public function tocheckadmin($userId){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users u
            INNER JOIN roles r
            ON r.roleId = u.roleId
            INNER JOIN permissions p
            ON p.roleId = r.roleId
            INNER JOIN module m
            ON m.moduleId = p.moduleId
            WHERE userId= $userId
            AND (p.view == 1 or p.add == 1 or p.edit == 1 or p.deleteRole == 1)";
}
```

Comment: If u get record then its admin else user. Then in controller u check if u have got any record from db or not. Based on that load the view.

Answer (score 1):

So, in the main index.php file change the application path, i.e. change this:

`$application_folder = 'application';`

To:

```
`$application_folder = 'application/frontend';`
```

For the admin application create a directory, let's say backend, put a copy of the index.php file there and make it point to the admin app, so:

```
$application_folder = 'application/admin';
```

To complete the operation put a copy of the .htaccess file inside the backend directory and change it to use this directory as base of the rewrites:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /backend/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by setting the users permissions in a session variable when logging them in.

```
$data = ['is_admin'     => true];
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

Then in the controllers for the admin area I do a check in the `__constructor()` method

```
    /**
     * login protect
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        if (!$this->session->userdata('is_admin')) {
            redirect('admin/account/login');
        }
    }
```

Here is the update code for your example with comments

```
/**
 * tocheckadmin
 */
public function tocheckadmin($admin_id)
{
    // get the admin
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users u
            INNER JOIN roles r
            ON r.roleId = u.roleId
            INNER JOIN permissions p
            ON p.roleId = r.roleId
            INNER JOIN module m
            ON m.moduleId = p.moduleId
            WHERE userId= $userId
            AND (p.view == 1 or p.add == 1 or p.edit == 1 or p.deleteRole == 1)";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->row(); // use row() to return a single object
}

/**
 *
 */
class Admin_controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("Adminmodel","",true);

        $userId =  $this->session->userdata('cp_adminid');

        $toCheck = $this->Adminmodel->tocheckadmin($userId);

        if ($toCheck === false) {

            // then the user is not an admin
            // redirect to the admin login

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I logged in as user but if I change url `http://localhost/ci3/admin/Adminhomepage` It will go to admin page. I have userId and permissions like view=0, add=0, edit=1 and deleteRole=0. The above code is not worked.

Comment: Do you have an `admin = 1` permission?